# Write acces blocked by Sitecore JSS workflow

Tags: jss

I have an issue that I cannot fix atm.

We created a new Security role and assigned rights to it. However Content Editors that have this role cannot edit any items as the JSS Workflow currently prohibits this, I am not sure where to change this. The newly created Role just has the ( Authoring and Sitecore Client Advanced Publishing ).

Please see attached screenshot for more info.

[image: write access declined by workflow]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try granting at least `Workflow State Write` to the role in question using Security Editor. Note that you may need to enable this permission type using the Columns dialog and assign it on the "Published" workflow state item.

[Enable this permission type using Columns dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uedfD.png)

[image]